# Why does the index come back as the same for both of the letters in this list?

Tags: python

So I'm indexing letters in a list. If I put the letters of "h" "e" "l" "l" "o" in the list and I try to get the index of them, it returns
0
1
2
2
4.
How do I get the second "l" to show up as 3?

```
def gameboard():
    print("_ " * len(secretword))
    for i in secretword:
        gameboardindexes.append("_ ")

def letterindexes():
    for i in secretword:
         wordindexes.append(i)

def guessLetter():
    guess = input("Please enter one letter: ")
    for i in wordindexes:
        if guess == i:
            x = wordindexes.index(i)
            print(x)

secretword = input("Please enter word:")
wordindexes = []
gameboardindexes = []
wrongletters = []


letterindexes()
gameboard()
guessLetter()
```

Comment: How should the game know which `l` you have guessed?

Comment: well i want it to know both "l"s if you have guessed it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python, the `index` method has the following parameters:

```
str.index(sub[, start[, end]] )
```

There is no way to control which index you are returned, as it will always return the first index possible. In this case, the first `l` is returned, so `2`.

If you would like to solve this issue, however, you can maintain the most recent `l` that was encountered. You can use a dictionary to store this value, and for the *next* call, you can pass this as the `start` argument.

Essentially, maintain a dictionary as follows, with all the other global variables:

```
most_recent = {}
```

Every time after running:

```
print(x)
```

Add this line:

```
most_recent[i] = x+1
```

Then, edit this line:

```
x = wordindexes.index(i)
```

To this:

```
x = 0
try:
    last = most_recent[i]
    x = wordindexes.index(i, last)
except:
    x = wordindexes.index(i)
```

This essentially checks if the letter has been found before, or not, and then edits search range to not include it again. This will not overwrite the word, but will guess every `l` (or any repeating letter) one at a time.

You will get `0 1 2 3 4` as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The list index function returns the index of the first occurrence. A workaround for this could be to create a string from the array and use the `rindex()` function. The `rindex()` function returns the last index where the substring was found.

```py
hello = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
''.join(char for char in hello).rindex('l')
```

Another possibility would be to provide the list index function a start index one past the first found index.

```py
hello = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
hello.index('l', hello.index('l') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have `guessLetter()` overwrite any letter for which it returns an index:

```
def guessLetter():
    guess = input("Please enter one letter: ")

    for letter in wordindexes:
        if guess == letter:
            index = wordindexes.index(letter)
            wordindexes[index] = 0
            return index

    return -1  # not found
```

**TEST**

```
>>> guessLetter()
Please enter one letter: l
2
>>> guessLetter()
Please enter one letter: l
3
>>> guessLetter()
Please enter one letter: l
-1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.join` with `str.rindex`:

```
print(''.join(yourList).rindex('l'))
```

Or use `enumerate`:

```
print([i for i,v in enumerate(yourList) if v == 'l'][-1])
```

Both output:

```
3
```